# Create html page and add css file to the html page using vb.net(Winforms)

Tags: html, css, vb.net, winforms

I have a normal `winform` and I would like to know is there any possibility to generate a `html page` and to add a `css file` to the html page from the `local folder`.

something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/css" src="MyDir/main.css"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I do this from the `codebehind`(logic part)not `web application codebehind` using `webbrowser control`.

Comment: Hard to understand what the issue is here - an html file is just a text file and .NET has any number of ways of creating a text file. You talk about winform - i.e. a desktop app - and then about codebehind which implies a web application. Finally you ask about the web broswer. You need to give us a bit more detail of what you want to do and what you are currently unable to do

Comment: Sorry actually it's a desktop application and codebehind in the sense the background code where we actually write the logic part and not the design.I need to design a html using webcontrol and in that html I need to add the css and jquery files from my local folder.

Comment: I am developing similar to http://visuallightbox.com/

Comment: Still struggling to understand what you can't do though given that HTML is just text...

Comment: Yes it's just text and can I do by adding document text property of webbrowser control.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create all your html and css files into a single folder or single hierarchy and use none or relative paths in link tags respectively. The webbrowser control treats relative paths the same on the local file system as it does with live domains.

So if you have a project directory called `Html`, put an html file in it as well as a css file. Insert a `<link href="Main.css" type="text/css" />` in the head of your html and you should be good to go.